# No Tourney or Altus parts on Shimano website?

Tags: parts, shimano

Why are there no Tourney or Altus parts on Shimano site, only Acera?

http://bike.shimano.com/publish/content/global_cycle/en/us/index/products/mountain/acera_9-speed.html?

Did they stop producing anything less than 9 speed? Or am I searching in the wrong place?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They still exist - they just aren't high enough in quality/product line to appear on the front page for Shimano (i.e. they aren't useful marketing points for Shimano, but you can still order parts in those groups from most cycling retailers - almost everyone who buys Tourney/Altus is an OEM or a bike shop who needs something very cheap for repairing BSO's; In fact, Tourney does appear on the better BSO's now, and Altus on the bottom rung of non-BSO's which is usually upgraded to Acera/Alivio when needed anyway).

Here is the link for [Tourney](http://techdocs.shimano.com/techdocs/blevel.jsp?FOLDER%3C%3Efolder_id=2534374302051870&ASSORTMENT%3C%3East_id=1408474395181679&bmUID=kosfvIl) and [Altus](http://techdocs.shimano.com/techdocs/blevel.jsp?FOLDER%3C%3Efolder_id=2534374302051836&ASSORTMENT%3C%3East_id=1408474395181679&bmUID=kosfvXE). If those links don't work, go to this [link](http://techdocs.shimano.com) and select them under the mountain bike drop down.

Also, for what its worth, heres something regarding personal experience: My commuter was a 7 speed bike with Acera trigger shifters. They happened to be damaged, and the only new part on the market for 7 speed was Tourney. The only way I could describe Tourney was "starts with s, ends with t, and the word isn't soot" - wouldn't stay in adjustment, horrible brake feel, etc.

Ended up throwing out the Tourney stuff shortly after, and upgrading to 8 speed and Alivio shifters and brake levers. Its not hard to find the 8 speed Alivio shifters anymore (despite them not being current), and I needed a new freewheel soon anyway (yes, my commuter runs a freewheel, not a cassette), so I took the plunge.

Comment: Thanks :) I own an LBS. Yet I'm new to bikes and to the market (I got the shop a half year ago), so I now searching for parts. In our country and especially in my region people are poor enough to get (almost) only low level parts...

Comment: Fair enough. Note that SRAM makes some parts under their "attack" line which are Shimano compatible.

Comment: Theres also Sunrace and Microshift shimano compatible shifters which may be cheaper as well.